# How to stop webrick server after calling it as a daemon (-d option)

Tags: debian, daemon

I have run Webrick server (Redmine) using this command:
`ruby script/rails server webrick -e production -d`. Now I would like to stop the server, but sending a SIGTERM signal or calling kill doesn't work. How to stop the server?

Comment: Can you post the output of `ps aux|grep ruby` ?

Answer (score 1):

Send it a `SIGKILL` (e.g. by calling `kill -9 <pid of ruby>` or `kill -KILL <pid of ruby>`).

Comment: That's what I did, but I hope there is a better solution - more process-friendly.

Answer (score -1):

You can just `pkill ruby` hoping that nothing else ruby runs ;-)

Comment: Sysadmins don't hope like this.

Comment: Use pkill -f -x ... if that comforts you